# How to use different fill colour for specific rectangles

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, android-view

Based on the code I've used for my canvas drawing and the screenshot regarding that, I'm trying to fill a specific rectangle with a different colour but instead this unexpected behaviour occurs where other rectangles change stroke colour also. Does anyone know what can be done fix this issue?

> **I only want the 2nd rectangle from the the left on the top row to be filled black & stroked red whilst the other rectangles remain with a red stroke**

```
public class Car extends View {
    public Car(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public Car(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public Car(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    Paint paint;

    private void init() {
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(4);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        int w = canvas.getWidth();
        int h = canvas.getHeight();

        int rectWidth = w / 5;
        int space = w / 15;
        int topRectHeight = getPaddingTop();
        int bottomRectHeight = getPaddingBottom();

        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); //add this
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            int left = i * (rectWidth + space);
            int right = left + rectWidth;

            if (i == 1){
                paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
            else{
                paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            }

            Rect rect = new Rect(left, 0, right, topRectHeight);
            canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);//add this
            Rect rect2 = new Rect(left, h - bottomRectHeight, right, h);
            canvas.drawRect(rect2, paint);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I only want the 2nd rectangle from the the left on the top row to be
>   filled black & stroked red whilst the other rectangles remain with a
>   red stroke

For this in the `if` Case when `i=1` you need to do two things

1. `setStyle` to **fill** and `setColor` to **black** and draw the rectangle.
2. Then again set back the `setStyle` to **stroke** and `setColor` to **red** and draw rect2 of yours.

Code:

```
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        int w = canvas.getWidth();
        int h = canvas.getHeight();

        int rectWidth = w / 5;
        int space = w / 15;
        int topRectHeight = getPaddingTop();
        int bottomRectHeight = getPaddingBottom();

        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); //add this
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            int left = i * (rectWidth + space);
            int right = left + rectWidth;

            if (i == 1){ 
                paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                Rect rect = new Rect(left, 0, right, topRectHeight);
                canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
                //again set back the style here
                paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                Rect rect2 = new Rect(left, 0, right, topRectHeight);
                canvas.drawRect(rect2, paint);
                //this will draw the lower rectangle! Using extra variable rect3 just for safer side.
                Rect rect3 = new Rect(left, h - bottomRectHeight, right, h);
                canvas.drawRect(rect3, paint);
            }else{
                Rect rect = new Rect(left, 0, right, topRectHeight);
                canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
                paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);//add this
                Rect rect2 = new Rect(left, h - bottomRectHeight, right, h);
                canvas.drawRect(rect2, paint);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Almost, although the red stroke isn't showing: [link to screenshot](http://picpaste.com/Screen_Shot_2015-08-28_at_18.41.09-mVUv7MY4.png)

Comment: Edited please check it, can you tell me, if its correct ?

Comment: Welcome, Happy to help.

Comment: Just double checked and one of the rectangles has now gone for some reason: http://picpaste.com/Screen_Shot_2015-08-28_at_18.58.44-RcRC4UkO.png